# Double sum over i and j with i \neq j

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I would like to represent a double sum with `i\neq j`. So I want two capital sigmas with text `i\neq j` underneath them. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Oops, I read the question wrongly, sorry for the noise: it doesn't really appear to be a duplicate.

Comment: Despite the requested double summation sign, I would usually write such a sum as `\( \sum_{i\ne j}... \)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`\mathop` allows you to perform operator-related things (like sub-/superscripting underneath/over top in display style) on non-operator symbols:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathop{\sum\sum}_{i\neq j} \]
\end{document}
```

Using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), it is also possible to declare a new operator, say `\sumsum`, if you're using this notation on a more frequent basis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sumsum}{\sum\sum}
\begin{document}
\[ \sumsum_{i\neq j} x_{ij} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar: \underset{i\neq j}{\sum\sum}

Comment: @Benjamin But remember that the classes like `\mathop` and similar are there for good reasons (spacing, interpretation, ...), therefore it is preffered to use `\mathop` or `\DeclareMathOperator`.